# If $h(x)=x \ln x$ , find $h'(x)$.

Tags: calculus, differential

I'm not sure how to differentiate this function. I guess you use the chain rule, but I am not getting the correct answer. Could someone show me how it's done?

Comment: Thank you! Then how would you integrate the derivative

Comment: Please make another question.

Comment: To integrate the derivative is simply to take the original function and add a constant to it. For example, $\int h'(x)dx=h(x)+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the product rule $(uv)' = u'v + uv'$:

$$\left ( x \ln x \right)' = x' \ln x + x (\ln x)' = \ln x + {x \over x} = \ln x + 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [product rule](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/productruledirectory/ProductRule.html):
$$h(x)=x\ln x$$
$$h'(x)=x\ln' x+x'\ln x$$
$\ln'(x)=\frac 1 x$ and $x'=1$, so substitute:
$$h'(x)=\frac x x+1\ln x$$
Simplify:
$$h'(x)=1+\ln x$$